# Avoid using a composite key

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a joint database table which has 3 columns just like the following example :

```
C TABLE 
----------------------------------------------------
ID_A VARCHAR FOREIGN KEY references A(id_A) PRIMARY KEY
ID_B VARCHAR FOREIGN KEY references B(id_B) PRIMARY KEY
DATE_OP DATE NOT NULL
```

[C is a joint table between A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyk7u.jpg)

I just wanted to know if i can avoid using a composite key in my implementation, by adding an autoincrement "ID" or a proper code as a primary key and add unique constraints on both the foreign key columns ? this way i will only have to refer that id in my business layer without worrying about any duplicates.

**EDIT** : when i said unique it meant that the couple (ID_A,ID_B) is declared UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a surrogate key.

The performance impact of adding a surrogate key will depend on which DBMS you're using, but overall it should be minimal if any. As long as you enforce the unique key, this shouldn't introduce any long-term problems. Using a surrogate key instead of a composite key as foreign key in related tables adds a level of indirection and may require joining with the C table in cases where it wouldn't be necessary with a composite key, but this is common practice and shouldn't be a significant issue. The surrogate key makes for a smaller foreign key than two varchars which means some queries may even be more efficient.

Comment: does it inflict any performance or show any DB design flaws at long term?
The main idea is that i want to make it easier to manipulate this joint class or table while working on my business layer.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your concerns. Hope that helps.